I have a weird space between two lines in my work
I have this wierd space on my title page:
Why?
This is my code:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[german]{babel}


\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm}

%def titelseite

\title{
{\textbf {\huge Synthetisierung von PLA mit Milchsäure}}\\
\vspace{15mm}
{\includegraphics[scale=1]{images/pla_titelblatt.png}\vspace{15mm}} \\
{\large{Flurin Maissen, 6Gb \\ Betreuerperson:Rocco Ciorciaro, Chemie \\ Maturaarbeit 2024, Technische Produktion \\ Bündner Kantonsschule, Gymnasium}}
}
\author{}
\date{}


%start dokument

\begin{document}


%titelseite

\maketitle 


You should finish your paragraph before switching back to another font size.

(also \large does not take an argument)

Addendum to David's comment: You are using package titling that already supports additional elements before or after the main title and before or after the author or date. So maybe you should read the manual of that package. But IMHO it would also make sense to just do the whole title design using a titlepage environment without using \maketitle.

@UlrichDiez oh centering, yes.

You're loading titling but not using its features.
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}


\graphicspath{ {images/} }

%def titelseite

\setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm}
\pretitle{\centering\huge\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\vspace{15mm}}
\preauthor{%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}\par
  \vspace{15mm}\large
}
\postauthor{\par}

\title{Synthetisierung von PLA \\ mit Milchsäure}
\author{Flurin Maissen, 6Gb \\
  Betreuerperson: Rocco Ciorciaro, Chemie \\
  Maturaarbeit 2024, Technische Produktion \\
  Bündner Kantonsschule, Gymnasium}

\date{}


%start dokument

\begin{document}

%titelseite

\maketitle 

\end{document}


I fixed german into ngerman, which should be the preferred option (it plays better with the Neue Rechtschreibung).
Also T1 is the mandatory encoding for German and inputenc is no longer necessary.

Compare
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\title{%
  \large 
  Line A\\
  Line B\\
  Line C%
}%
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle 

\end{document}

to
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\title{%
  {% 
  \large 
  Line A\\
  Line B\\
  Line C%
  }%
}%
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle 

\end{document}

With the second example you get unexpected vertical space between Line B and Line C.
Reason:
With the second example \large is placed into a local scope. Therefore, when finishing the last line of the paragraph which makes the title, i.e., when finishing the line "Line C", fontsize is back to fontsize set by \maketitle which  is larger than \large and thus has a larger \baselineskip.
Remark by Wipet about how the difference in values of \baselineskip comes into being:
It can be added that \\ runs \par in this title context. So, each \\ creates a line which is immediately inserted to the vertical mode with respect to the current \baselineskip. The end group } resets the \baselineskip to larger value and then the \maketitle macro processes \par. This creates the last line and it is inserted to the vertical mode with respect to this different \baselineskip value.

It can be added that \ runs \par in this title context. So, each \ creates a line which is immediately inserted to the vertical mode with respect to the current \baselineskip. The end group } re-sets the \baselineskip to larger value and then the \maketitle macro processes \par. This creates the last line and it is inserted to the vertical mode with respect to this different \baselineskip value.

@wipet I took the freedom to verbatim-copy your remark into the answer. In return, feel free to edit the answer if you feel the need or have the wish to do so.
